# Link keeps firing when I pass in a parameter even with .preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I want to pass the event and to prevent default but also pass the *ID* as a parameter so I can use it in my function.

When I do this the link still fires

```
<a href="" id="stylinglink" class="specialhover" onlick="show(event, this)">
```

```
function show(event, elem) {
    event.preventDefault;
    var id = $(elem).attr("id");
    alert(id);

    // after the alert the function breaks and the link fires

    switch(id) {
    case stylinglink:
        var x = ".stylingspecial";
        hide(x);
        break;
    }
```

The `hide(x)` refers to another function.

Comment: I am sure the `onlick` is a typo. Since you are using jquery, why not do the entire handler with jquery and remove the onclick

Comment: Hotfix : `onclick="return show(event, this);`. Best fix : don't use inline handlers.

Comment: why not do the entire handler with jquery? please enlighten me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecbuilder/rty5acfr/3/)**

```
$("#stylinglink").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(id);

    switch(id) {
    case 'stylinglink':
        var x = ".stylingspecial";
        hide(x);
        break;
    }
});

function hide(x){alert(x);}
```

**REFER**

http://api.jquery.com/click/